# Code produced by v8 turbofan

Tags: javascript, v8

I am trying to understand the scheme of Google V8.

It seems clear that the Turbofan compiler uses bytecode produced by the Ignition interpreter. But I can't understand, what happens to the code (optimised), which comes from Turbofan.

Is the code produced by  Turbofan executed by the CPU?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Generating executable code is what compilers do.